# cv2.imdecode() returns None from image in base64, mimetype image/jpeg received via Websockets

Tags: python, opencv, websocket, base64, video-streaming

I use websockets to receive video frames. Image is encoded in base64 mimetype image/jpeg. I'm trying to convert image to np.ndarray. When I read image file code works correct. But when I'm trying to read image from socket stream, issue is occured.

```
        image_data = base64.b64decode(part.encoded_image)
        np_array = np.frombuffer(image_data, np.uint8)
        image = cv2.imdecode(np_array, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

In docs cv2.imdecode() returns None in case when image is short or corrupted. My image is in HD format, 1280/720. Data isn't corrupted as I could successfully decode it using online converter.
This is the beginning of received data:

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIfIiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv/

Comment: So the `image` variable is showing `None`?

Comment: you have to skip `data:image/jpeg;base64,` before decoding. Your `base64` data starts at `/9j/4AAQSkZJ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to skip `data:image/jpeg;base64,` to get only `base64` data which will give you correct image data and `cv2` will decode and display it.

In example I use `split(',', 1)` for this - it gives me `data:image/jpeg;base64,` in variable `header` and image data in `data`.

I use full image in code.

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import cv2

encoded_image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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'

header, data = encoded_image.split(',', 1)
#print('header:', header)
#print('  data:', data[:20])

image_data = base64.b64decode(data)
#print('result:', image_data[:20])

np_array = np.frombuffer(image_data, np.uint8)
#print(' array:', np_array[:2])

image = cv2.imdecode(np_array, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
#print(' image:', image[:2])

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

(face image with size 7x7)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! The first solution that worked for me after a couple of hours of searching. Have a great day! :)